# Drupal User Object

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm trying to create a custom user profile in Drupal 7. One of the fields references the user object, and I can't figure out what the syntax is to do that. I've read that '->' should be used, but I'm not sure exactly how.

The structure of a `print_r($user_object)` is at: http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1741565

I'm trying to get to the data inside `field_country[data]` - just not sure how to do it.

In addition, when I try to access `$user_object[user_relationships_ui]`, nothing is visible. It doesn't throw an error, but doesn't print anything, either.

Thanks for the help

Comment: How well do you understand PHP and object-oriented programming?

Comment: I haven't done too much with PHP and OOP- I understand the concepts, but not the syntax, or exactly how it works.

Comment: Check out @goldenparrot's answer. Make sure you're aware of the structure and type of the data you're trying to access before you write the code.

Answer (score 0):

The way I figured out how to do it was to cast the object as an array -

```
$user_object= (array) $user_profile['field_country']['#object'];
```

After that, I could access it as a normal array.

Answer (score -1):

Attributes of an object in php must be accessed by `->property_name`. And, when using associated arrays, using `['key_name']`.

Here, `$user_object[0]['user_relationship_ui']['#type']` gives you the `#type`.

Don't confuse objects with associated arrays.

EDIT:
Further explaining,

and see line 18, 19:

```
[field_country] => Array (
                    [#theme] => field
```

see line 31, 32:

```
[#object] => stdClass Object (
                            [uid] => 1
```

The difference is if you want to access `#theme`, you have to do it by using `['#theme']`. And if you want to access `uid`, you have to do `['#object']->uid`.

Comment: The structure of what I'm looking for is user_profile[field_country][

Comment: so why isn't it $user_object[0]->['user_relationship_ui']->['#type']? I'm trying to access an object inside an associative array, and am not sure what syntax to use.

Comment: An object will have `stdClass` as it's type when `print_r`ing or `var_dump`ing. `$user_relationships_ui` is of type Array. So, you can't `->` it.